# How to get "send/share via gsconnect" actions on nautilus actions in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, gnome-shell-extension, nautilus-actions, kde-connect

Is there a way to add "share via gsconnect" option in nautilus actions?

Comment: Using 22.04, for me it didn't appear, until I gave all the read/write rights on my mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a right-click entry called "Send to Mobile Device" is available.

I'm using Debian 10 with 3.30, and installed [this Gnome-shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/)

I don't remember of any additional installation, but try to add `nautilus-sendto` and `nautilus-python` too if required.

Note that your smartphone should be connected to the same wifi network and paired in GSConnect

This tutorial could be of interest: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/connect-android-ubuntu-gsconnect

EDIT: you may need to restart Nautilus to see this new entry

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didnt work even after following the tutorial because i didnt restart nuatilus.

Comment: Thanks @xenos, I updated my answer to add a reminder

Comment: I also needed to install `nautilus-python` (Python bindings for Nautilus) for it to work for me.

Comment: Thank you @MiguelGuthridge, I updated my answer to add your comment

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04 do `sudo apt install python3-nautilus gir1.2-nautilus-3.0`